# Assembly[AT&T syntax] "jmp *0x80497e8(,%eax,4)"

Tags: linux, assembly, gdb

I have the following instruction: `**"jmp  *0x80497e8(,%eax,4)"**`
The value at *0x80497e8 is **0x8048be0** *[an adress as expected..]*
So where should the program jump to? How do I calculate the value? 
I am asking since *(,%eax,4)* should be *%eax*4* 
I am using GDB and **when %eax is 0**, indeed the program jumps to *0x8048be0 + 0*

But when **%eax is 5**, it does not go at 0x8048be0 + 20, which is *0x8048bf4*

Comment: It will jump to whatever address is in memory at `*(0x80497e8+20)`.

Comment: Are you sure 0x80497e8+20 come in the same parenthesis and the * symbol applies to both? I do not think so... If it were so it would jump to a memory address which is not even an instruction...

Comment: Yes, you can trust @EOF :) If you are confused, switch gdb to intel syntax using `set disassembly-flavor intel`.

Comment: x86 address encodeing in AT&T-syntax: `offset(base, index, scale)`. The whole thing is an address.

Comment: Solved! Thanks! I imagined the * symbol only applies to that first address, not to the whole expression. All clear now!